# Which out of QImage, QPixmap, and QPainter should be preferred for what reason?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Considering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466636/462608

> Do you have the diagram in a QImage or a QPixmap? Then you can use image providers to expose the diagram to QML, and draw it into a Image element.
>   Do you have the code that uses a QPainter to draw it, and want to make a QML element that uses such code? In that case, subclass QDeclarativeItem (in Qt Quick 1) or QQuickPaintedItem (Qt Quick 2), override their paint() methods and do the drawing there. You can then register the new type in the QML engine, so you can use a Diagram type in your QML files.

***Which out of QImage, QPixmap, and QPainter should be preferred for what reason?***

Comment: The question is irrelevant, as you need `QPainter` to draw anyway. The preferred way to do it with Qt Quick 2 is the scene graph & Open GL API.